# aggregated frequency count in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'd like to write a cypher query which will tell me how frequently a particular node property occurs in a set of matches. For example, in

```
MATCH (:left)-->(p:right)
```

I'd like to know how many times the `right` nodes `p.id` are `"id 1"` or `"id 2"` and so on.

Currently I'm returning all the matches and then (using a separate tool -  python) counting the number of times each `id` occurs in the records.

I'm sure there must be a way to do this purely in cypher using `DISTINCT`, `collect()` and `count()`, but I've got myself stuck...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what your are searching is this query :

```
MATCH (:left)-->(p:right)
RETURN p.id, count(DISTINCT p)
```

Cheers

Comment: I think the `DISTINCT` may not be necessary.

Comment: `DISTINCT` shall be removed (Neo4j 3.5.5)